awk: does the placement of the curly brace { matter?
I have two bash scripts that execute some an awk script. It's supposed to filter out blocked users:
testawk.sh:
#!/usr/bin/bash 

awk_script_file=$(cat << 'EOF'

$0 ~ "User " user ".* blocked"
{
    print
}
EOF
)

# Run awk through bash to get file globbing to work
bash -c "awk -v user='${user}' '${awk_script_file}' ${file}"

testawk2.sh:
#!/usr/bin/bash 

awk_script_file=$(cat << 'EOF'

$0 ~ "User " user ".* blocked" {
    print
}
EOF
)

# Run awk through bash to get file globbing to work
bash -c "awk -v user='${user}' '${awk_script_file}' ${file}"

You can see that literally the only difference is the placement of the curly brace { at the end of the regex matchphrase.
Now when I run this script against test data (user=evil_user;file=data.csv; . testawk.sh) I get different results.
data.csv:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
User evil_user blocked: Limit exceeded
ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 
User evil_user blocked: Limit exceeded
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

testawk.sh outpout:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
User evil_user blocked: Limit exceeded
User evil_user blocked: Limit exceeded
ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 
User evil_user blocked: Limit exceeded
User evil_user blocked: Limit exceeded
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

testawk2.sh output:
User evil_user blocked: Limit exceeded
User evil_user blocked: Limit exceeded

And I don't understand why?
Note: The indirection of calling bash within the script is to allow filepath globbing expansion for ${file}.

Why are you calling bash to call awk at the bottom? you're already in bash.  The extra layer of bash -c doesn't help anything

@MarkReed It does, but not in this case. In production I use it for bash filepath expansion, to alllow globbing patterns in ${file}.

OK. I think eval would be more straightforward; it would at least avoid the extra shell process. And would not be notably more dangerous, since your current approach already leaves you vulnerable to injection attacks via the content of $file.

Just don't quote $file if you want it to be exposed to the shell for globbing and filename expansion, you don't need to wrap everything in bash -c.

Just curious - why do you store your awk script in a variable (var='BEGIN{echo "hello"}'; awk "$var") instead of interpreting it in-place (awk 'BEGIN{echo "hello"}') in the midst of the rest of your code or wrapping the call in a function (prthello() { awk 'BEGIN{echo "hello"}'; }; prthello) to avoid cluttering where it's called?

@EdMorton Just for readability's sake. And for not needing to escape characters. I'm curious: What would your general scriptfile look like?

@glades I posted an "answer" showing how I'd write your script at https://stackoverflow.com/a/78385408/1745001. It's not an answer to your question so please don't accept it as one, you already have answers to your question, it's just responding to your comment best I can on this forum.

To answer the title: Yes.
In an awk condition/action pair, the action has to start on the same line as the condition; Awk is not a freeform language, as newlines are significant.
So when you do this:
/whatever/
{ something }

It is interpreted as the condition /whatever/ with no explicit action (that therefore triggers the default action of "print the record") followed by the action block { something } with no explicit condition (that therefore is triggered on every record).
So the program winds up both printing every line that matches /whatever/ and doing the { something } to every single line, whether it matches /whatever/ or not. If part of the { something } is printing out the line, the lines that do match /whatever/ will be printed twice.


And I don't understand why?

Because newlines in awk scripts are significant.  This follows in part from the fact that awk allows either the pattern or the action of any rule to be omitted. It relies on the end of a pattern appearing on the same line as the beginning of an action to associate the pattern with the action, instead of treating them as an actionless pattern followed by a patternless action.  There are considerable additional rules about where newlines may appear (unescaped) and where not, too.
The default pattern matches every line, and the default action is { print },
so this ...
$0 ~ "User " user ".* blocked"
{
    print
}


... says "print every line that matches pattern $0 ~ "User " user ".* blocked", and, additionally, print every line".  On the other hand, this ...
$0 ~ "User " user ".* blocked" {
    print
}

... says "print every line line that matches pattern $0 ~ "User " user ".* blocked"".  Of course, that could also be written as simply
$0 ~ "User " user ".* blocked"


The OP already has answers to the question they asked, this isn't an answer it's a response to the OPs comment asking to see how I'd write their code instead of storing the awk script in a variable and then using bash -c to call awk as they are doing.
This is what the OP is doing:
awk_script_file=$(cat << 'EOF'

$0 ~ "User " user ".* blocked" {
    print
}
EOF
)

some shell code...

bash -c "awk -v user='${user}' '${awk_script_file}' ${file}"

other shell code...

Below are various ways I'd rewrite the OPs script, assuming file contains a globbing pattern such as:
file='foo*'

If the script is really just to print the line matching the RE:

Get rid of the { print } and just call it in-place since it's so brief:

some shell code...

awk -v user="$user" '$0 ~ ("User " user " .* blocked")' $file

other shell code...

You could put it in a function if you prefer of course. I removed the unnecessary { print } as that's the default behavior when a condition is true.
Note that I added a blank before .* blocked so a user name like johnston wouldn't falsely match a desired user value of john. If there is no blank in that location in the input then do something else dependent on the input format to avoid false matches. The parens are just for clarity (and to stop my left eye twitching as I try to guess/remember if a ~ b c means (a ~ b) c or a ~ (b c) and whether or not the rule for that is portable to all awks :-) ).
Assuming we need to do more than just print and so need an action block:

Call it in-place:

some shell code...

awk -v user="$user" '
    $0 ~ ("User " user " .* blocked") {
        print
    }
' $file

other shell code...


or store it in a function and call that function in-place:

prtuser() {
    awk -v user="$1" '
        $0 ~ ("User " user " .* blocked") {
            print
        }
    ' "${@:2}"
}

some shell code...

prtuser "$user" $file

other shell code...

In reality I'd concatenate the strings to form the regexp just once at the start of the script:
BEGIN { userRe = "User " user " .* blocked" }
$0 ~ userRe

instead of doing the concatenation once per input line:
$0 ~ ("User " user " .* blocked")

but that's just a minor efficiency consideration.

Thx I adapted my script and it seems to work just as fine :)

You're welcome. AFAIK there are only 2 "reasons" to store a script in a variable and they are a) because you use a shell syntax highlighting editor that gets confused by inline awk scripts, or b) because when you do a ps on some system (maybe old Solaris versions?) it shows the whole awk script in the output and your sys admins don't like it for some reason. Neither are issues I've actually come across myself in the past 40+ years of shell programming and if I did I still wouldn't store a script in a variable, I'd use a different editor and/or tell the sys admins to get over it.
